# Given two Cantor sets $C_1$ , $C_2$ ⊂ [0, 1], there exists a continuous bijection f : [0,1] → [0,1] such that f($C_1$) = $C_2$.

Tags: real-analysis

My problem about this question is I can find a function f which is continuous on a cantor set $C_1$ , but how to extend this function from $C_1$ to [0, 1] then? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Extend it to be linear on each interval of the complement.